# Jackson @ResponseBody custom serialization on Spring @Controller per method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

I Have a Java Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FOO("fee", "The fee foo", "lorem ipsum"),
    BAR("bee", "The bar bee", "ipsum lorem"),
    BAZ("boo", "The baz boo", "blah blah");

    private final String id;
    private final String summary;
    private final String description;

    @JsonValue
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

the `@JsonValue` is intentional as I want the id to be returned as the "value" by default in most JSON serializations (e.g. `"fee"`), however for my rest controller, I would like to Serialize the enum with all its properties:

```
@Controller
public class MyEnumController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/my-enum-types", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<MyEnum[]> getMyEnumTypes() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(MyEnum.values());
    }

    /*
        desired output: "[
            {
                "id": "fee",
                "summary: "The fee foo",
                "description": "lorem ipsum"
            }, 
            ...
        ]"

        actual output: "[
            "fee",
            "bee",
            "boo"
        ]"
    */
}
```

I have attempted to annotate the enum class with `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` however it seems as though the `@JsonValue` annotation overrides this configuration. removing @JsonValue from the class fixes this, but if I did that, every other class containing a `MyEnum` attribute would need to have `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.String)` to get the actual enum name or `@JsonSerialize(using = MyEnumToIdPropertySerialzer.class)` to get the original `@JsonValue` behaviour (as far as I am aware).

I'm also aware of media types being configurable with custom representations of an object in a REST fashion (e.g. `application/vnd.com.example.full_enum+json`), but this seems quite involved for something that will only happen occasionally. I'm willing to accept if this is the most appropriate approach but I would also have hoped that simply annotating the controller method with something like `@WithCustomSerializer(using = MyEnumSerializer.class, for = MyEnum.class)` would save me from these configuration woes.

**Is there an annotation-idiomatic way of declaring a `@Controller` method to include custom serialization per method instead of its default (`@JsonValue`) class annotated behaviour?**

### UPDATE:

I think I need to clarify after the previous answer that I don't want my controller to be returning a list of strings. I would like to have its signature remain as an Array of `MyEnum`s as that is what it should be.

Any annotations on the class will effect the JSON serialization globally and I would like to keep its global representation the way I've annotated the class already.

Comment: Please see my response in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528581/custom-serialization-of-single-restcontroller-endpoint/54102912#54102912), maybe this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum MyEnum {

    FOO("fee", "The fee foo", "lorem ipsum"),
    BAR("bee", "The bar bee", "ipsum lorem"),
    BAZ("boo", "The baz boo", "blah blah");

    @JsonProperty
    private final String id;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String summary;
    @JsonProperty
    private final String description;

    private MyEnum(String id, String summary, String description) {
        this.id=id;
        this.summary=summary;
        this.description=description;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you required actual Enum value call   MyEnum.BAR.toString().