# Custom serialization of single @RestController endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

Is there a way (preferably some type of annotation) to register a custom serializer for a single endpoint in a `@RestController`? Extending the bean and putting a `@JsonSerialize` on it would be an option, but that demands an otherwise pretty useless new bean class. I tried the following:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/some_endpoint/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SomeType someEndpoint() {
    return someObject;
}
```

But the `@JsonSerialize` annotation doesn't appear to have any meaning to Spring in that context. Is there an alternative or is the extra bean class my only option?

Comment: produces attribute to requestmapping? Why is method returning Object instead of actual type?

Comment: It's just a quick draft method, I'll edit it. What do you mean in your first question?

Comment: `@RequestMapping` has attribute called produces. If you assign value to "application/json", it should work

Comment: It produces JSON already. I'm happy with Spring's default serializer except for that single endpoint. That endpoint must be serialized to JSON as well, but I need to do some heavy filtering on my return type's properties (which would be much to complicated for me to do with a `@JsonView` btw)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@JsonView(View.Summary::class)` in the attributes you want to add or ignore and in the method you want to apply that view, for example:

```
public class View {
    public interface Summary
} 

public class A{
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
private String serialized = "",
private String notSerialized = ""}
```

and then in the controller:

```
@JsonView(View.Summary.class)
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public A getA(){
    return A() 
}
```

If you want to reverse the JsonView (serialize the atributtes who doesnt have the view). you can add the following propertie: `spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true`